# How to save the cookie

Tags: javascript, fetch, setcookie

I'm trying to verify permissions when login. The server response with the set-cookie but the browser didn't save the cookie although I set the headers 'credentials' with 'include'.

Here is my code.

```
const baseUrl = '';
export default async(url = '', data = {}, type = 'GET', method = 'fetch') => {
    type = type.toUpperCase();
    url = baseUrl + url;

    if (type === 'GET') {
        let dataStr = '';
        Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
            dataStr += `${key}=${data[key]}&`;
        });

        if (dataStr !== '') {
            dataStr = dataStr.substr(0, dataStr.lastIndexOf('&'));
            url = `${url}?${dataStr}`;
        }
    }

    if (window.fetch && method === 'fetch') {
        const requestConfig = {
            credentials: 'include',
            method: type,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': '*/*'
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'force-cache'
        };

        if (type === 'POST') {
            Object.defineProperty(requestConfig, 'body', {
                value: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
        }

        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, requestConfig);
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    } else {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let requestObj;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                requestObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                requestObj = new ActiveXObject();
            }

            let sendData = '';
            if (type === 'POST') {
                sendData = JSON.stringify(data);
            }

            requestObj.open(type, url, true);
            requestObj.setRequestHeader();
            requestObj.send(sendData);

            requestObj.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (requestObj.readyState === 4) {
                    if (requestObj.status === 200) {
                        let obj = requestObj.response;
                        if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
                            obj = JSON.parse(obj);
                        }
                        resolve(obj);
                    } else {
                        reject(requestObj);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    }
};
```

Then I fetch the url and the server response OK and set cookie. When I check the cookie in the browser, It does not exist。This indeed confused me. So how can I solve the problem.

Comment: you are not setting the cookie anywhere at all\

Comment: The fetch API should save the cookie when I set the credentials, in addition I cannot get the cookie with document.cookie when  the server  response headers with set-cookie

Comment: maybe it should..., but it appears that it isn't. You should learn to write your own code don't let them provoking apis make you their slave.